# VBA - run time 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying this command

```
Sub Name() 
Dim n As Integer
Do Until Cells(2, n) = "" 
    n = n + 1 
    Cells(2, n).Value = n 
Loop
End Sub
```

But I had "runtime error 1004 : Application-defined or object-defined error" Message. 
what am I missing here?

Comment: `Cells(2, n) = ""` is never going to equal `""` because you're always filling it in - eventually you're going to run out of columns - What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Furthermore you need to set `n` before entering the loop otherwise that first line is going to fail before the loop can even start. `Do Until Cells(2, 0) = ""` is causing the error (because n hasn't been set yet). But.. then you'll have a loop that will throw an error at 32767 iteration when your integer runs over the limit based on @dwirony's comment.

Comment: And all of this could just be done with a cell formula `=Column()` and copy and paste into the range where you want this value.

Comment: hey @dwirony I'm trying to make a code that programmaticly Inserts values in Serial Number fieldfrom the first record until the last record I have ( I don't know which cells will be the last record)  that why I'm using (n, 2) in my code.

Comment: `Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(2,columns.count).end(xltoleft)).value = activesheet.evaluate("INDEX(COLUMN(" & Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(2,columns.count).end(xltoleft)).Address(0,0) & ",)"`

Comment: You need to select an answer for this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, you will loop forever because your cell will always have a value as it's assigned and then checked for for a value. Move the n increment after you assign the current cell's value. Then, your check will be be correct.

```
Sub Name() 
    Dim n As Integer
    n=1 ' initialize N to where you want to start.
    Do Until Cells(2, n) = ""   
        Cells(2, n).Value = n 
        n = n + 1 //move this line to end of loop.
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Maybe the sub name is incorrect, also you can stop the loop if the column n+1=""

EDIT: Another thing I forgot to try was, `do until cells(1,n)<>=""`

```
Sub nn()
    Dim n
    n = 1
    Do Until Cells(2, n + 1) = ""
        n = n + 1
        Cells(2, n).Value = n
    Loop

End Sub
```